# Popular um Chart.js com ajax.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Fala galera, estou com uma dúvida aqui no meu projeto. Eu tenho um gráfico que é desse jeito: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu quero popular ele com os dados de um webservice em PHP, qua vai retornar um JSON e em cada botão que ele clicar, eu faço uma requisição nova. Sabendo que o método de armazenar os dados dele é assim:

`data: [
                [1, 34],
                [2, 25],
                [3, 19],
                [4, 34],
                [5, 32],
                [6, 44]
            ]
        };`

Agora a minha dúvida é: Como eu faço pra alocar os dados dessa maneira no 'data' do gráfico? Supondo que meu JSON venha assim:

```
   [
    {
        "content":[
            {
                "data": "2015-05-05",
                "volume": "280"
            },
            {
                "data": "2015-05-06",
                "volume": "20"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Eu já tive dificuldades de usar dados de requisição ajax em gráficos e acabei deixando porco com PHP no meio mesmo, mas dessa vez não tem jeito haha.
Se alguém souber como ajudar ficarei grato.
Abraços.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Populando Chart.js com dados de requisição AJAX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172663/populando-chart-js-com-dados-de-requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando JSON.parse é possível acessar os dados dentro do JSON retornado, como é mostrado no exemplo abaixo:

```
var retorno =
{
    "content":[
        {
            "data": "2015-05-05",
            "volume": "280"
        },
        {
            "data": "2015-05-06",
            "volume": "20"
        }
    ]
}
objeto = JSON.parse(retorno);
objeto.content[1].data; // "2015-05-05"
objeto.content[1].volume; // "280"
objeto.content[2].data; // "2015-05-06"
objeto.content[2].volume; // "20"
```

Comment: entendi, mas para eu colocar esses dados dentro do chart eu faria como? levando em conta o modelo ali de data

Comment: No server-side: Coloque uma resposta do tipo JSON igual o atributo content. No front com JS, faça uma requisição AJAX, e coloque a resposta em content